# I have this error while trying to run my code. System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String. (Parameter 's')

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I had this error while trying to run my code.

System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String. (Parameter 's')

below is the code.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = jwtConfig["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = jwtConfig["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtConfig["Jwt:SecretKey"]))
    };
});
```

and the json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=InvoiceAppDB;Trusted_Connection=True"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "https://localhost:7063/",
    "Audience": "https://localhost:7063/",
    "SecretKey": "your_secret_key",
    "ExpirationInMinutes": 60
  },
```

I have tried changed the jwt settings in the appsettings.json still getting the same error

Comment: What is `jwtConfig`?

Comment: Where is the error actually being thrown from?

Comment: If `jwtConfig = builder.Configuration` then it should work fine. Please provide more details.